# Is there a better way to decode JSON data that has a repeating variable with different counts?

Tags: json, swift

For example, say there is an API which returns JSON with the following keys. Sometimes the keys can have one ingredient or twenty. Is there a better way than listing all the possible outcomes in my model? Can I set this up programmatically?

```
let strIngredient1: String?
let strIngredient2: String?
let strIngredient3: String?
let strIngredient4: String?
let strIngredient5: String?
let strIngredient6: String?
let strIngredient7: String?
let strIngredient8: String?
let strIngredient9: String?
let strIngredient10: String?
let strIngredient11: String?
let strIngredient12: String?
let strIngredient13: String?
let strIngredient14: String?
let strIngredient15: String?
let strIngredient16: String?
let strIngredient17: String?
let strIngredient18: String?
let strIngredient19: String?
let strIngredient20: String?
```

I am referring to this API's json data:
https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=53049

Comment: What is the *actual* JSON data? That looks like an absolutely terrible API. That should simply be an array.

Comment: @luk2302 Oh it is very real and very terrible. https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=53049

Comment: You can create a `struct RawKey: CodingKey`, get a container keyed by `RawKey` and create every key from a string. You can also list `allKeys` on a container.

Comment: Seeing how strange is the JSON, I wouldn't use `Codable`. I'd use old JSONSerialization with a custom struct, where you'd have a `[Ingredients]`, corresponding to `strIngredient` & `strMeasure`.

Comment: This api is so strange that it has generated questions several times before here on SO, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64265867/how-to-parse-json-using-custom-decoder-init-with-incrementing-keys-in-swift) is one example

Comment: Can you please show the json?

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution:

```
struct RawCodingKey: CodingKey {
    let stringValue: String
    let intValue: Int?

    init(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
        intValue = nil
    }

    init(intValue: Int) {
        stringValue = "\(intValue)"
        self.intValue = intValue
    }
}

...

let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: RawCodingKey.self)

let ingredients = try 1...20.map { index in
   try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: RawCodingKey(stringValue: "strIngredient\(index)"))
}
```

You might want to add `compactMap`, trimming spaces and filtering empty strings to remove invalid items.